# Routing in multitenancy site

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, multi-tenant

I have a multitenacy WebSite, and i need to solve the routing so that:

A request enters to

```
www.maindomain.com/{site}/{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

First, a global filter is executed, and stores the current site on ViewData

```
ViewData["tenant"] = current {controller} request
```

And then, the correct controller/action is executed, so that it can retrive the request's site:

```
 public class ViewItem : Controller 
 {
   public ActionResult ViewItem(int id) 
   {
     string site = ViewData["tenant"];
     return View("you are viewing the item" + id + " from tenant" + tenant ;
   }
 }
```

I think i need to configure some routing, is it possible?

Comment: Where is `tenant` varaible populated?

Comment: just add the area in solution explorer...

Comment: the ViewData["tenant"] is defined in the global filter, with the current {site} of the request url

Comment: maxs87, i dont understand your answer, can you give me a link or somethig?

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom `ActionFilter`. The trick is to hook into `OnActionExecuting` method, which is called *before* the action method in controller.

```
public class PropagateTenantToViewDataFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Controller.ViewData["tenant"] =
            filterContext.RouteData.Values["tenant"];
    }
}
```

Register this filter as a global filter for all controllers and actions - add this line to your `Application_Start` method in `Global.asax.cs` file:

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new PropagateTenantToViewDataFilter());
```

If you are using `App_Start` and `FilterConfig`, then add the following line to your `RegisterGlobalFilters` instead:

```
filters.Add(new PropagateTenantToViewDataFilter());
```

See e.g. [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410209%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more information about Action Filters in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Nice, i thought that using the actions link would be a problem, but they keep the current tenant on the url.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at [Autofac mutli tennancy](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/MultitenantIntegration) it made our lives a lot easier.  Can define a tenant identification strategy and use that to make DI decisions allowing tenant specific services or controllers etc.

Comment: great, but i need a fast solution, i have developed the site with other multitenant design, and now i need to do a easy change...